# Bootstrap Carousel: indicators with variables not cycling

Tags: bootstrap-4, handlebars.js

I have a carousel in Bootstrap v4.6.0:

```
<div id="myc{{idcarousel}}" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
```

I use indicators and controls as follows:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
{{#each imagefile as |item|}}
{{#if @first}} 
        <li data-target="#myc{{idcarousel}}" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li> 
    {{else}} 
    <li data-target="#myc{{idcarousel}}" data-slide-to="{{@index}}"></li>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

```
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myc{{idcarousel}}" role="button" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myc{{idcarousel}}" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

But only the controls work. When I click on the indicators, the images don't slide.
How can I address the data-target of the indicators differently?
Thank you for a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Why easy if complicated is another option. I now use a handlebars helper.

```
helpers: {
  mycar: function(value) {
       return "#myc" + value;
 }
}


<ol class="carousel-indicators">
{{#each datei as |item|}}
{{#if @first}} 
        <li data-target="{{mycar ../idcarousel}}" data-slide-to="0" class="active"> 
</li> 
    {{else}} 
    <li data-target="{{mycar ../idcarousel}}" data-slide-to="{{@index}}"></li>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
</ol>
```

greetings